# Reshaping a dataframe by moving part of an existing row to a new row

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have data in the format:

```
structure(list(choice = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("option1", 
"option2"), class = "factor"), option1var1 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "A", class = "factor"), option1var2 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("B", "H"), class = "factor"), option2var1 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("C", "F", "I"), class = "factor"), option2var2 = structure(1:4, .Label = c("D", 
"E", "G", "K"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("choice", "option1var1", 
"option1var2", "option2var1", "option2var2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

[image: Existing data]

with six columns. The first column contains respondent ID, the second column contains data about a choice made by a respondent (either option1 or option2), columns 3 and 4 contain attributes associated with option1, and columns 4 and 5 contain attributes associated with option2.

I want to transform the dataframe so that it looks like this:

```
structure(list(respondent = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), 
    choice = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), option = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("option1", "option2"
    ), class = "factor"), var1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 3L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "C", "F", "I"), class = "factor"), 
    var2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("B", 
    "D", "E", "G", "H", "K"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("respondent", 
"choice", "option", "var1", "var2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

[image: Desired result]

This requires splitting each row into two, leaving option1 data in one row and moving option2 data to another row, as well as creating a new numeric variable with information on which choice (option1 or option2 each respondent choice).

There doesn't seem to be any information on this type of transformation available--neither here nor in R documentation that I've found. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the original data frame is `df1` and the final output is `df2`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(respondent = 1:n()) %>%
  gather(Option, Value, starts_with("option")) %>%
  separate(Option, into = c("option", "Var"), sep = 7) %>%
  mutate(choice = ifelse(choice == option, 1L, 0L)) %>%
  spread(Var, Value) %>%
  select(respondent, choice, option, starts_with("var")) %>%
  arrange(respondent, option)
df2
#   respondent choice  option var1 var2
# 1          1      1 option1    A    B
# 2          1      0 option2    C    D
# 3          2      1 option1    A    B
# 4          2      0 option2    C    E
# 5          3      0 option1    A    B
# 6          3      1 option2    F    G
# 7          4      1 option1    A    H
# 8          4      0 option2    I    K
```